# Build failing on sqlserver driver for nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, node-sqlserver

I'm trying to install `node-sqlserver` for my application in the `node_modules` directory by typing the following command,

> npm install node-sqlserver

This is what I get,

```
npm WARN package.json application-name@0.0.1 No README.md file found!
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No README.md file found!
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sqlserver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/node-sqlserver
npm WARN deprecated node-sqlserver@0.1.0: This package has been superseded by msnodesql.

> node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\Songify\node_modules\node-sqlserver
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\Songify\node_modules\node-sqlserver>node "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node
-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
gyp ERR! rebuild error Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at failNoPython (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\con
figure.js:85:14)
gyp ERR! rebuild error     at Object.oncomplete (C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\li
b\configure.js:59:11)
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-sqlserver package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-sqlserver
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\
\npm-cli.js" "install" "node-sqlserver"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\Songify\node_modules
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.37
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message node-sqlserver@0.1.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Tarun\Desktop\Songify\node_modules\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code undefined
npm ERR! not ok code 1
```

How do I resolve this issue? I'm using `express` as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is in the output, you need to install python, following that you will get another error, you will need to install Microsoft SDK for Windows Server 2008 and dot net framework 3.5